# debugger showing -> 'this' is not available in onResponse method of volley for Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have this silly problem.
I searched for it but couldn't get any anwser hence I posted it here.

In following fragment I have recyclerview which populate data from server with **Post POJO** with help of **Gson**.

I have use similar code many times in my another projects, but today I got an error due to which my recyclerview is not showing values. So I debug code and I got following output which shows **'this' is not available** for my recycleview inside *onResponse* of Volley.

My Fragment class is as follows:

```
public class Seller_Corner_Tab2 extends Fragment implements PostAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

public static final String TAG = Seller_Corner_Tab2.class.getSimpleName();

RecyclerView recyclerView;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
AppPreferences preferences;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seller_corner_tab2,container,false);

    preferences = new AppPreferences(getActivity());

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.seller_corner_2_rv);
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManagerVertical = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()); // (Context context)
    mLinearLayoutManagerVertical.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManagerVertical);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

    /*progressDialog.setMessage("Loading your Posts");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();*/
    fetchSellerPosts();

    return view;
}

public void fetchSellerPosts() {

    final Seller seller = EKrushiKattaApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getSeller();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            EndPoints.GETPOSTBYID, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            ArrayList<Post>templist = new ArrayList<>();
            /*progressDialog.hide();*/
            try {
                GsonBuilder gsonbuilder= new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson=gsonbuilder.create();
                Log.e("Response",response);
                templist =gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<List<Post>>(){}.getType());

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            recyclerView.setAdapter( new PostAdapter(templist,getContext(),Seller_Corner_Tab2.this));

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.hide();
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            Log.e(TAG, "Connection error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put(CommonLib.SELLER_ID,String.valueOf(seller.getSellerId()));

            Log.e(TAG, "params: " + params.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding request to request queue
    EKrushiKattaApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(Post post) {

}}
```

My debugger showing me this output

[image]

My PostAdapter Class is as follows :

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<Post> posts;
private Context context;
private OnItemClickListener listener;

public PostAdapter(ArrayList<Post> posts, Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.posts = posts;
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(posts!=null){

        final Post post = posts.get(position);

            holder.title.setText(post.getPostTitle());
            holder.desc.setText(post.getPostDescription());
            holder.cost.setText(post.getPostCost());

            RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .centerCrop()
                   // .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                  //  .error(R.drawable.ic_pic_error)
                    .priority(Priority.HIGH);

            new GlideImageLoader(holder.image,
                    holder.progressBar).load(EndPoints.BASE_URL+post.getPostImage(),options);

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(post);
                }
            });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int size=0;
    try {
        size = posts.size();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return size;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView image;
    TextView title,desc,cost;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_image);
        title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_title);
        desc=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_desc);
        cost=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_cost);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_progressbar);
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(Post post);
}}
```

Comment: Do you get any error or it's just in the debugger?

Comment: it just in debugger but my recyclerview is showing nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1) Pull the data source creation out of the `onResponse()`

2) Create adapter right after recycler view inflation.

3) In `onResponse()` fill data source with new data.

4) Call `notifyDatasetChanged()` in adapter.

```
public class Seller_Corner_Tab2 extends Fragment implements PostAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

public static final String TAG = Seller_Corner_Tab2.class.getSimpleName();

RecyclerView recyclerView;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
AppPreferences preferences;
ArrayList<Post>templist = new ArrayList<>();
PostAdapter adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seller_corner_tab2,container,false);

    preferences = new AppPreferences(getActivity());

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.seller_corner_2_rv);
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManagerVertical = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()); // (Context context)
    mLinearLayoutManagerVertical.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManagerVertical);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    adapter =  new PostAdapter(templist,getContext(),this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    /*progressDialog.setMessage("Loading your Posts");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();*/
    fetchSellerPosts();

    return view;
}

public void fetchSellerPosts() {

    final Seller seller = EKrushiKattaApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getSeller();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            EndPoints.GETPOSTBYID, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            ArrayList<Post> newList = new ArrayList();
            /*progressDialog.hide();*/
            try {
                GsonBuilder gsonbuilder= new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson=gsonbuilder.create();
                Log.e("Response",response);
                templist =gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<List<Post>>(){}.getType());

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            templist.addAll(newList);
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();




        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.hide();
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            Log.e(TAG, "Connection error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put(CommonLib.SELLER_ID,String.valueOf(seller.getSellerId()));

            Log.e(TAG, "params: " + params.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding request to request queue
    EKrushiKattaApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(Post post) {

}}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it is not working !!! Now for templist it is showing -> 'this' is not available, in debugger

Comment: your recycler view still not populated?

Comment: No !!!! It is showing 'this' is not available for both templist and adapter

Comment: Probably you have an issue with your Adapter. Can you update your question with the adapter's code?

Comment: is your build variant debug?

Comment: I have updated my question with adapter's code @Eselfar

Comment: @ParikshitChalke I see in your screenshot that you have access to the variable this (the Fragment) can you check if you can see the recyclerview and the adapter inside it? Could you post a screenshot with that variable collapsed?